# Add interface to all classes with a certain naming pattern

Tags: regex, visual-studio, replace, resharper, regex-lookarounds

I am looking to refactor a large number of classes.

All the classes follow the naming convention

```
class SomethingModel
```

I want to find them all and replace them with

```
class SomethingModel : IModel
```

But I also want to exclude some template derives I have that look like

```
class SomethingController : GenController<SomethingModel>
```

I am trying to do this in Visual Studio.

The obvious choice is regex Find and Replace but I also have Resharper and **Ideally I would do it using the pattern search replace**

Through some searching on regex questions I have got the first part working

```
(?<=class)(.*Model)
```

but I cant seem to exclude the template. I am starting to play with

```
(class .*Model)(?!"(?<="Generic"))
```

I very rarely use regex and if there is a none-regex solution I would much prefer it. In particular I would quite like to use Resharper Search with Pattern

Which I tried the following with:
[image]
Which worked really well....apart from all my classes became empty... the statements tag does not seem to work (set to inifinite)

**UPDATE**

Positive cases:

- public class DoorModel
- public class HandleModel
- public class BellModel

Negative cases

- public class DoorController : GenericController
- public class WindowModel : IModel

Comment: that special case is ot clear to me. you want to match all classes ending with "Model" that do not already implement an interface or inherit from some class? maybe a list of positive matches and stuff that shouldn't match would be helpful

Comment: Nice idea! But I don't think there's a placeholder for type members - the statements placeholder matches the content of type members, but we don't have anything to match the type members themselves.

Comment: @nozzleman added negative and positive lists

Comment: @citizenmatt ahh I see, shame I imagine this is a common problem with EF generated models

Comment: @chrispepper1989 sth. along the lines of https://regex101.com/r/aMaPwF/2 ?

Comment: @nozzleman that's a great start but I wouldn't want to get rid of the class name, which I could do in this instance by just selecting the "Model" part. That's a great resource!

Comment: if you mean you only want to match `Model` in you positive cases, i guess this isn't possible with plain regex, since it would require a non fixed size positive lookbehind, which isn't supported :(

Comment: @nozzleman bah, what about matching the space directly after Model so essentiall public class somethingmodel * so something like this https://regex101.com/r/Gikvdg/1 that takes into account that class has to proceed model?

Comment: @chrispepper1989 Have a look at the substitutions in https://regex101.com/r/aMaPwF/4 is this what you want to achieve?

Comment: YES! wow that is a useful regex trick! add as the answer and I will mark it as best :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127198/discussion-between-chrispepper1989-and-nozzleman).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try to match

```
(?<=class\s)(\w+Model)(?!\s+:\s*(GenericController|IModel))
```

and replace using the first capturing group like this

```
\1 : IModel
```

as seen in https://regex101.com/r/aMaPwF/4

Comment: Great answer, sadly visual studio does not seem to support "\1" However notepad++ does, so I opened all files in that and did "Replace All in All Opened Documents :)

Answer (score 3):

There is a hacky solution if you do wish to leverage Resharper. But its a hack.

According to Jetbrains the pattern search and replace is designed for functions, which is why it doesn't handle my class example above very well (see my conversation [here](https://disqus.com/home/discussion/jetbrains/structural_search_and_replace/?utm_source=reply&utm_medium=email&utm_content=read_more#comment-2979094477) )

What I did was open all the files I wanted to edit and did a find replace to replace to get resharper to ignore my class contents.

I wanted my resharper pattern replace so that I could replace this pattern:

```
class $ClassName$ : IModel
{

}
```

with this one

```
class $ClassName$ : AbstractModel<$ClassName$s>{}
```

So I simply did a find replace that replaced "**IModel**" with "**IModel{}//$$**"

Then ran the resharper pattern replace, which then worked because it obviously didnt "see" the contents of the class anymore.

Then I just replaced ">{}//$$" with ">"  (hence the extra crazy symbols).

So yer its very hacky, but it does work. Thankfully its very rare you want to do crazy stuff like this (and should generally avoid it all costs). I actually discovered a few other "Resharper hacks" while messing around with this code which I might have to post about later.